# How can i make border blur

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following simple full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class A2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const A2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<A2> createState() => _A2State();
}

class _A2State extends State<A2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: ( bounds) {
            return LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.white.withOpacity(0.05),Colors.white],
                stops: const [0.0, 0.09],
                tileMode: TileMode.mirror,
                begin: Alignment.center,
                end: Alignment.center
            ).createShader(bounds);
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 100),
            ),
          ),
        )

    );
  }
}
```

Question : how could i make the borders blur .

i tried to use `ShaderMask` but the problem i cannot align the blur direction into the required area as shown in the following image

[image]

Note: i need only the border who get blur

[image]

i am trying to make the blur area into where the green circles painted only

i don't want the white part being affected by blur . ONLY BORDERS

Comment: How about using shadow?

Comment: i have no idea .. can you please give example as answer if it near of the blur

Comment: Color will be faded toward center ? It will be easier if can include desire output image

Comment: and by the way . you deleted your answer in my other question . sorry that was my bad .. your answer was what i need .. if you re answer the same one i will accept it .. basically the code in this question was your answer but pop up new issue with blur Lol

Comment: I've undeleted that, if I am not wrong you didnt include blur on that question, anyway can you include an exact image for this ourput?

Comment: that was other need . not about blur but you answer it correctly .. ok i am going now to make edit for  desire output

Comment: @YeasinSheikh please take a look . i  marked the required areas with green circles

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correct.

Alternative (imitate a border) is to create a parent container with padding (ex. 2px) and make it blur and in the child container you can put whatever content you like.

Check this package. https://pub.dev/packages/blurrycontainer